# What is a partial order? Are $<$ and $\le$ partial orders?

Tags: order-theory

According to Jech's set theory, a partial ordering (of $P$) is:

> A binary relation $<\subseteq P\times P$ where we have:
>
> 1. $\forall p\in P[(p,p)\notin <]$ (which we may say as: $\forall p\in P[p\not<p$])
> 2. $\forall p,q,r\in P[p<q\wedge q<r\implies p<r]$

It then goes on to say if $<$ is a partial order then we can define a relation $\le$ where $p\le q\iff[p=q\vee p<q]$ and that is a partial order.

However this violates point 1 of the definition of partial orders.

It notes that

> "$<$ is sometimes called a strict order"

I have a theorem that shows there is a 1:1 correspondance between strict and "non-strict" orderings, so perhaps this is more of a "we may as well call it a partial, for it is induced by and induces exactly one partial order"

Comment: I just looked up the book and the part you're talking about seems very unclear and poorly written. I was going to write an answer but Clive's is fine. Maybe find another book. :)

Comment: @avid19 yes it is a weak section on it. I'll see what Maurin has to say.

Comment: When someone has satisfactorily answered your question, you should upvote and accept their answer. This demonstrates your appreciation and rewards the answerer for writing his answer and is far better than "thanks bye" to your subject line.

Comment: @avid19 please do add to something, no offense to the answerer but all he's said is "yeah you're suspicions are right", how does it fit into the greater picture of orders (are these special cases of total orders?) should I be writing "let (thing) be a strict order" or "strict partial order" , I don't want to ask a second question but I am certainly not informed on the issue now!

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the term *partial order*, when unqualified by any other adjectives, refers to a reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive relation (i.e. the $\le$ you mention). A *strict (partial) order* is an irreflexive, transitive relation (i.e. the $<$ you mention).

As you mention, given a set $X$, there is a correspondence between partial orders and strict partial orders on $X$;

- Given a partial order $\le$, there is a strict partial order $<$ defined by $$x < y \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x \le y \text{ and } x \ne y$$
- Given a strict partial order $<$, there is a partial order $\le$ defined by
  $$x \le y \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x < y \text{ or } x = y$$

So really, referring to strict partial orders simply as "partial orders" is a (forgivable) abuse of notation.